# linq select C# to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, c#-to-vb.net

I need the following LINQ statement corverted to VB.net. but

```
collection.Select(c => {c.PropertyToSet = value; return c;});
```

Here's what I have, but I want to do the 'return' instruction.

```
collection.Select(function (c) c.PropertyToSet = value  ***return c***  )
```

Any ideas on how to get that converted?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: A LINQ query should not have side-effects. Modifying a property when you select it is clearly a side-effect. Use a loop.

Comment: This is a misuse of the `Select` method. `LINQ` is for querying, not modifying objects. At the very least such code is not thread-safe. Multiple iterations will result in multiple *and unexpected* modifications. Imagine calling this method twice with two different values, then iterating over the first result again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change all properties of an object in the collection, `Select` method is not appropriated method to do this.

Since the `collection` object is a `List(Of T)`, you could try this with `ForEach` method:

```
collection.ForEach(Sub(c) c.PropertyToSet = value)
```

With `Select` method, you could try this:

```
collection = collection.Select(Sub(c) c.PropertyToSet = value)
```

Alternatively, you could use the language structure `For Each` for it:

```
For Each c as YourType In collection
    c.PropertyToSet = value
Next
```

Comment: `ForEach` is a list-method and doesn't work If collection is an array

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the way, did not test it but it should work

```
                Collection.Select(Function(c)
                                      c.PropertyToSet = value
                                      Return c
                                  End Function)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get a filtered IList back, try this:

```
collection.Where(Function(c) c.PropertyToSet = Value).ToList
```